# How to use snprintf when using a pointer to char

Tags: c

Right now I'm using `sprintf` but want to change to `snprintf`.

My question is, what is the best way to secure that I'm not doing a buffer overflow, when I'm doing something like the code below using pointer:

This is a quick example of the code, in my code the `string_pos += get_line_to_buffer(&string[string_pos]);` is called multiple times. So I'm gonna add alot of data to the buffer and therefore I want to make sure I'm not writing too much.

```
int main(void){
    char string[50];
    size_t string_pos = 0;

    string_pos += get_line_to_buffer(&string[string_pos]);
}

static size_t get_line_to_buffer(char *buffer){
    char* p = buffer;

    p += sprintf(p, "%d,%s,%s,%lu", version, fileName, Id, timestamp);
    p += sprintf(p, ",%d,%d,%f", noOfObs, frequency, sum);
    p += sprintf(p, ",%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
    p += sprintf(p, ",%f,%d", speed, errorCode);
    p += sprintf(p, "\r\n");

    return p - buffer;
}
```

Comment: `string_pos` is uninitialized in your example: the code won't work right.

Comment: you'll have to pass the (remaining) buffer space to the `get_line_to_buffer` function as an extra parameter.

Comment: Is it necessary to have 5 `snprintf` calls? Solution would be simpler if you'd combine these into single call.

Comment: It's not necessary, it just looks prettier when looking at the code xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read carefully [documentation of `snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (and/or the Linux one, [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html)). Notice that it could fail by returning a negative value. And you could be interested by its `%n`.

You need to know the size of the buffer. A good way is to pass it as a second argument to your `get_line_to_buffer` function:

```
ssize_t get_line_to_buffer(char *buffer, size_t siz) {
  char* p = buffer;
  char* start = buffer;
  char* end = buffer + siz;
  int n = 0;
  if (p < end)
     n = snprintf(p, siz, "%d, %s, %s, %lu", version, fileName, Id, timestamp);
  else
     n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d, %s, %s, %lu", version, fileName, Id, timestamp);
  if (n<0) return -1;
  p += n, siz -= n;
  if (siz<0) return -1;
  if (p < end)
     n = snprintf(p, siz, ",%d,%d,%f", noOfObs, frequency, sum);
  else
      n = snprintf(NULL, 0, ",%d,%d,%f", noOfObs, frequency, sum);
  if (n<0) return -1;
  p += n; siz -= n;
  return p - start;
}
```

Actually, you could consider using [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) if your system has it.

And you might instead open a in-memory stream with [fmemopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) or [open_memstream(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html) and use `fprintf` on it.

BTW, you might simply do a single `snprintf` but split its format control string in several physical lines:

```
int n = snprintf(p, siz,  
                 "%d, %s, %s, %lu"
                 ",%d,%d,%f",
                 version, fileName, Id, timestamp,
                 noOfObs, frequency, sum);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll do a single snprintf - When using a pointer, can this go wrong when calculating the size?